# What happens if a shell script runs something interactive?

Tags: linux

What happens if a shell script executed by `crontab` runs something interactive, that is, something blocking because it is awaiting user input?

For example, my script might call:

```
certbot --preferred-challenges=http \
--manual-auth-hook /root/copychallenge.sh \
--manual-cleanup-hook /root/renewcomplete.sh \
-d buggs.com -d lotsa.buggs.com
```

Certbot is warning that the certificate is not ready to be renewed yet. Will the shell just stay open forever, using memory in the background?

Comment: I just found something called `timeout` for `crontab` which looks promising. I'm guessing not having a timeout here will lead to a slow memory leak?

Comment: Yes it works :) So you're implying there's no timeout at all without the `timeout` command?

Answer (score 0):

If `timeout` is not used, the process will stay waiting in the background until killed, or the server is rebooted.